# Signal Python script to send output

Tags: python, bash, signals

I am running a bash script after every 3 minutes. There is another python script running indefinitely and continuously which is collecting data from sensors continuously. Basically there is a variable in this Python script, say 'count' whose value I want to get after every 3 mins to this bash script and I want to set this variable to 0 in this python script. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: there are plenty of options, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656933/communicating-with-a-running-python-daemon

Comment: try using a common file. like write from python script to the file and when read from shell script change the value to zero